# How can I determine, if a templated class is a sublass of another templated class, as the templates might differ?

Tags: c++, templates, types, dynamic-cast

Consider the following class structure:

```
template <typename TType>
struct Base {public: virtual ~Base() {} };

template <typename TType>
struct Child : Base<TType> {};

template <template<typename> class Node, typename TType>
bool type(Node <TType>* node){
   return dynamic_cast<Base<TType>*>(node) == nullptr;
}

int main(){
   Child<int> child;
   type(&child);
}
```

This code works fine, as long as the child has the same template type before and after casting. If this is not the case, it will of course fail. If they have different types and I provide the specific type of the inherited template, it will work, but I have a very big number of possible templates. My first instinct was to add another template:

```
template <template<typename TType> class Node, typename TType, typename TType2>
bool type(Node <TType>* node){
   return dynamic_cast<Base<TType2>*>(node) == nullptr;
}
```

This will give an error "couldn't deduce template parameter", because the compiler does not know which type it is, as no corresponding parameter is passed (but I am not able to provide this in beforehand).

Is there any solution to this? I am also open to other possibilites than dynamic_cast, as my actual goal is, if the templated node is a subclass of the also templated baseclass.

I tried e.g. is_base_of without success. Something around the lines of `is_base_of<Base, typeid(child)>::value` did not work because of a type msimatch in the arguments.

Comment: "*tried e.g. is_base_of without success*" Maybe you can show your attempts to let us know where the problem is.

Comment: @康桓瑋 I added what I have tried.

Comment: What is `Base1`? And you should use `decltype` instead of `typeid`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 I corrected this, but unfortunaly when using base_of you have to specify the template.

Comment: Usually, one either use static typing with template or dynamic typing with OOP. Mixing both, you most likely get the drawback of both than the benefit of both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use overload:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr std::true_type IsBaseT(const Base<T>*) { return {}; }

constexpr std::false_type IsBaseT(const void*) { return {}; }
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3haYdqqTj)

That assumes accessible, non ambiguous base. And result is based on static type.

So you can turn that into a traits:

```
template <typename T>
std::true_type IsBaseTImpl(const Base<T>*); // No impl
std::false_type IsBaseTImpl(const void*); // No impl

template <typename T>
using IsBaseT = decltype(IsBaseTImpl(std::declval<T*>()));
```

And a more generic form:

```
template <template <typname> C, typename T>
std::true_type IsCTImpl(const C<T>*); // No impl
template <template <typname> C>
std::false_type IsCTImpl(const void*); // No impl

template <template <typname> C, typename T>
using IsCT = decltype(IsCTImpl<C>(std::declval<T*>()));

template <typename T>
using IsBaseT = IsCT<Base, T>;
```

Comment: This solution works. I have to cover multiple cases, with different parent classes and I need to distinct, which parent class is correct (like if class is subclass of one class do this, if it is a subclass of another one, do this and so on). Do I need to implement the two functions for each case or is there a shorter way to do this? (I am also confused that C++ does not seem to have a native way to do this with templated classes).

Comment: you can add a template template parameter. I added the code.